# Display & Retrieve Special Characters (\r\n\t) in Input Value

Tags: javascript

When setting & getting strings with special characters to input value, is there any other option besides repeated regex escape/unescape?

The text sequence MUST display them as characters in a single line (the same way they are shown here `\r\n\t`).

Example:

```js
const obj = {
  "text": "This is line one\nLine two\r\nLine three with tab\there."
}

input.value = obj.text;

// result: This is line oneLine twoLine three with tabhere.
```

In above case, special characters are lost and text show as
`This is line oneLine twoLine three with tabhere.`

Escaping special characters will display them in the text ...

```js
input.value = obj.text.replace(/\r/g, '\\r').replace(/\n/g, '\\n').replace(/\t/g, '\\t');

// result: This is line one\nLine two\r\nLine three with tab\there.
```

Unescaping special characters when saving them back ...

```js
obj.text = input.value.replace(/\\r/g, '\r').replace(/\\n/g, '\n').replace(/\\t/g, '\t');

// result: This is line one\nLine two\r\nLine three with tab\there.
```

Is there a better method to achieve the same result?

For example ... `JSON.stringify()` can escape but adds other characters i.e.

```js
input.value = JSON.stringify(obj.text);

// result: "This is line one\nLine two\r\nLine three with tab\there."
```

Comment: `Input` is only single line, if you want multiple use a `textarea`

Comment: @Keith There seems to be a misunderstanding. It HAS to display as escaped characters in a single line and not as an actual new line or tab.

Comment: No, there isn’t much of a different way. Removing line breaks out of a value is part of the “job” of a single-line text input, and a tab has no proper, defined representation in HTML to begin with. You _want_ to transform the input data you have here into something different - so you will actually have to _do it_ as well, it’s not gonna happen by any magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display special characters as one line in an HTML input, then you can just use JSON.stringify, it does this already.  And of course handles tabs & carriage returns.  You can also just splice of the extra double quotes it creates, and then place into the input.

The advantage it's obviously a tried and tested encoding / decoding feature of JS, so if you later want to JSON.parse, you could just add the double quotes back in.

eg..

```js
const obj = {
  "text": "This is line one\nLine two\r\nLine three with tab\there."
}

const ta =
  document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
const input =
  document.querySelector('input');
  
ta[0].value = obj.text;

input.value =
  JSON.stringify(obj.text).slice(1, -1);
  
function buildConverted() {
  obj.text = JSON.parse(
    `"${input.value}"`);
  ta[1].value = JSON.stringify(obj, null, '  ');
}

buildConverted();
 
input.addEventListener('input',buildConverted);
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Original
<textarea rows="3" readonly></textarea>

Input
<input/>

JSON

<textarea rows="7" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: Sounds good for displaying. What about retrieving? Since it will turn them into double escaped e.g. `This is line one\\nLine two\\r\\nLine three with tab\\there.`

Comment: @erosman  Like I said, add the double quotes back in and `JSON.parse('"' + input.value + '"')`

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. When I get back the value from the input to save. I have to `JSON.stringify(data);` That would result in `'\n'` getting double slashed to `'\\n'` which is not wanted.

Comment: Why would it?,  doing JSON.parse is going to remove the double `\\n`, and convert to just `\n`..  IOW: it's going to go back to what the object was initially..

Comment: @erosman  You need to put back into the `obj.text`,  I've updated the snippet to show it working.   You can then see the original is identical to the converted, it's a live demo too so change the input text to see the JSON, and obj updating.

Comment: Sorry... I misunderstood. Thank you for taking time and explaining it.